# complex ng-class expression containing both a value and a conditional

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-class

Say I wanted to have an ng-class do two things:

1) populate a value from a variable like so

```
 `ng-class="myAwesomeJavaScriptVariable"`
```

and

2) conditionally set a predefined class:

```
  `ng-class = "{awesomeClass: myAwesomeBoolean}`
```

I am aware that I could do something like
      `class="{{myAwesomeJavaScriptVariable}}" ng-class="{awesomeClass: myAwesomeBoolean}"`

How (if this is even possible) could I amalgamate those two into a single ng-class expression?

Comment: Think these need to remain separate, ng-class is just going to modify the class attribute on the DOM element and expects a map from class to boolean.  In the docs it says it can be this or a string list of class names or an array but I don't think you can mix these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Abraham P:

To Set Both the Conditional Statement and Scope Variable as Class

`ng-class="[{awesomeClass: myAwesomeBoolean},myAwesomeJavaScriptVariable]"`

This Will Work Fine.

Answer (score 3):

I think it might be:

```
data-ng-class = "{ myAwesomeJavaScriptVariable, awesomeClass: myAwesomeBoolean }"
```

Alternatively:

```
   class = "{{ myAwesomeJavaScriptVariable}} left clearfix" data-ng-class="{awesomeClass: myAwesomeBoolean }"
```

Comment: Second syntax have better readability. And used in places like [this](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/template/modal/window.html#L1).